# UINavigationController with 3 tables

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating an app that uses a navigation controller.
In the the first view I have three different table views.

How can I make the tables open a new view in the navigation controller when one cell is selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` as a delegate method on the view controller that shows the three table views, and in this method you initialize the new view controller you want to show and push it onto the screen by doing something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // TODO: Find out what view controller to push based on the tableView and the indexPath.

    UIViewController *viewController = [[YourSpecialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

Comment: I have that code in all the tables view control.. how i put they as delegate in the view controller??? i had tried in the interface builder select the table and put the delegate and data source of it dragging to him self.

Comment: No, that's the new view you want to open when a cell is selected.

Comment: it don t work because my [self navigation] is null in the tableview subclass.. any idea why it don t get the navigator form the class who initiate and have the uinavigatorcontrol??

Comment: A table view should not be its own delegate or data source. Separating models, views, and controllers is essential to Cocoa. You should add the table view(s) to a view controller, that in your case should be shown in a navigation controller. It's the view controller that should be the table view delegate and data source.